# $\textbf{C}$-Monoids and products

Tags: category-theory, products, monoidal-categories

i have a question about $\textbf{C}$-Monoids. We can make a new category $\textbf{Mon(C)}$ from the category $\textbf{C}$, namely the category of all $\textbf{C}$-monoids. A $\textbf{C}$-monoid is a triple $(A,m:A\times A\rightarrow A, e:1\rightarrow A)$ with $1$ a terminal object and $m$ associative and $e$ a unit. The statement i want to prove is that $\textbf{Mon(C)}$ has binary products. But how to define the multiplication in a product of two $\textbf{C}$-monoids? And how to show the uniqueness etc. The product and the UMP are clear for me (thus the definition) but this is a big step. Can someone help me?

Comment: This is straight forward. First do the case $C = \mathsf{Set}$.

Comment: In the category of sets the $\textbf{Sets}$-monoids are the monoids by usual definition. I prove this already.

Comment: I imagine $\mathcal{C}$ has finite products. Show that finite products (or, indeed, any limits that exist) in $\mathbf{Mon}(\mathcal{C})$ are created by the forgetful functor.

Comment: Yes $C$ has finite products, but i want to show this componentswise by explicit definition of such a product and by proving the UMP of a product.

Comment: For your definition of monoids you have to assume that $C$ has finite products. Your task is to show that $Mon(C)$ has finite products. Well, first do the case $C=\mathsf{Set}$. The general case is similar / identical / can be reduced to this (depending on your perspective).

Answer (score 1):

Let $(A,m,e)$ and $(A',m',e')$ be $\bf C$-monoids. Then their product will be
$$(A\times A',\,\bar m,\, (e,e'))$$
where $\bar m$ is composed with the canonical isomorphism 
$$A\times A'\times A\times A' \ \overset{\cong}\longrightarrow\ A\times A\times A'\times A'\ \overset{(m,m')}\longrightarrow\ A\times A'\,.$$